# How do I unit-test saving file to the disk with FileUtils?

Tags: java, apache-commons-io

I know this variation has been asked before.

But, One of my functions is using [Common's FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)). Here, it only takes File object and String. Is there any way to unit test this?

Comment: Can you include your function's code in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. Use a temporary folder, save your file there, and delete the folder after the test.

If you use JUnit, look at the [`TemporaryFolder`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html) JUnit rule (it creates a temp folder for you and takes care of the deleting).

Example code:

```
public class YourTest {
  @Rule
  public TemporaryFolder folder= new TemporaryFolder();

  @Test
  public void testUsingTempFolder() throws IOException {
      String filePath = folder.newFile("myfile.txt").getAbsolutePath();
      FileUtils.writeFile(filePath, "some String");
      assertTrue(new File(filePath).exists());
  }
}
```